# Reference for the statement that the complement of an affine open has codimension one

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The following statement seems to be "well-known", but I am unable to find a reference in the standard literature. Could someone suggest a reference?

Let $X$ be a separated normal connected Noetherian scheme and $U$ a (nonempty) affine open subset. Then the complement $Y = X \smallsetminus U$ has pure codimension one.

Comment: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BCQ provides the result you are looking for.

Comment: EGA IV, part 4 (IHES no 32), Cor. 21.12.7.

Comment: I'd've called this "algebraic Hartogs' theorem". If $Y$ is codimension 2 in $X$, then functions on $U$ should extend across $Y$, i.e. $U$ shouldn't be affine.